# с++ работа regex_search

Tags: c++, std-regex

Есть следующий код, занимающийся поиском элементов в строке. Почему-то ф-ия regex_search выдает ошибку в заданных элементах, конкретно в string переменной s. Не могу понять, почему это происходит, ведь первым аргументом функции должна быть string переменная. Что с этим делать?

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <regex>
 using namespace std;

 void main()
 {
  ifstream tx("Text.txt");
  string s,temp;
  std::cmatch res;
  std::regex r ("scientist");
  while (tx >> temp)
  {
      s.append(temp);
      s.push_back(' ');
  }
  cout << s;
  std::regex regex_search(s, res, r);
}
```

Comment: для начала main должен возвращать int. И что за: `std::regex regex_search(s, res, r)`?

Comment: main может иметь тип void, во всяком случае Vstudio позволяет. На работу программы это не повлияет.  std::regex regex_search(s, res, r); Должна находить в s совпадения с r и записывать их в res. Видел несколько подобных примеров, только мой не робит.

Comment: во-первых, согласно СТАНДАРТУ main ДОЛЖНА иметь сигнатуру int main() или int main(int argc, char **argv). Во-вторых, почитайте как в с/с++ вызываются функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ее надо использовать примерно так (я взял готовую строку, не из файла)

```
string s = "sav asgyv sadg sd bj jkfseb scientist, djkb, scientisttemp";
std::smatch res;
std::regex r("scientist");
cout << s << endl;;
while (regex_search(s, res, r))
{
    cout << res.str() << " + " << res.suffix() << endl;
    s = res.suffix();
};
```

То, что вы написали, даже не вызов функции...